# Fourier coefficient of complex measure (Exercise in Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Problem:** Suppose $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure on $[0,2\pi)$, and define the Fourier coefficients of $\mu$ by
>   $$\hat{\mu}(n)=\int_{[0,2\pi)}e^{-int}d\mu(t),\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
>   Assume that $\hat{\mu}(n)\to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$ and prove that then $\hat{\mu}(n)\to 0$ as $n\to-\infty$.

**Source:** Exercise 7 in Chapter 6 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

**Attempt:** Rudin gives the hint that we can reduce to the case $\mu\geq0$. I was able to do this without too much difficulty. The idea is that we can replace $d\mu$ by $pd\mu$ if $p$ is any trigonometric polynomial, and hence by $fd\mu$ if $f$ is continuous, and therefore if $f$ is a bounded Borel function (by Lusin's theorem). Hence, since $d\mu=hd|\mu|$ for some $h\in L^1(|\mu|)$ with $|h|=1$, and since bounded functions are dense in $L^1(|\mu|)$, we can replace $d\mu$ by $d|\mu|$.

But then I am not sure how to proceed. We know that a bounded Borel measure on an interval $I$ is regular (special case of Theorem 2.18). And $|\mu|$ is bounded since $\mu$ is a complex measure. So $|\mu|$ is regular. Hence:

> Is it true that if $\mu$ is a positive bounded regular Borel measure on a bounded interval $[0,2\pi)$ and $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ are periodic functions satisfying
>   $$\int_I f_n(t)d\mu(t)\to 0,\quad\text{as }n\to\infty$$
>   then necessarily
>   $$\int_I f_n(-t)d\mu(t)\to0,\quad\text{as }n\to\infty?$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have reduced it to the case $\mu \geq 0$, just "evaluate" the integral:

$\int e^{-int}d\mu=\int\cos(nt)d\mu-i\int\sin(nt)d\mu$. So $\hat{\mu}(n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ tells you that the real and complex parts of the above integral goes to $0$.

Now, use the fact that $\cos(-nt)=\cos(nt)$ and $\sin(-nt)=-\sin(nt)$ to get your statement.

Comment: Alternatively, $\hat{\mu}(-n) = \overline{\hat{\mu}(n)}$ if $\mu$ is real-valued.